# watchOS 7: How to render an inset grouped list as in the watchOS 7 Camera app?

Tags: watchos, watchos-7

(Cross post: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/657933)

At around 8:47 in the WWDC 2020 video "What's New in watchOS Design", in the example of a More button for the watch Camera app, a sheet is presented with a "robust set of options" which are rendered in a style somewhat similar to the iOS UITableViewStyle.insetGrouped / InsetGroupedListStyle. However, InsetGroupedListStyle isn't exposed on watchOS 7.

[image: inset grouped-style appearance on watchOS 7]

The closest analog I could see was when you embed a Picker into a List, the picker is rendered as a title/subtitle cell, and tapping on that cell presents a modal sheet with that one Picker's list of options in the same inset grouped style. However, this isn't an exact match - this picker has to be in a list, rather than a More button, and the picker only selects from one set of options, as opposed to multiple heterogeneous groups of options.

Can anyone provide guidance on how to render a sheet with multiple, heterogeneous groups of options, like the Camera app's More sheet, in this video?

Comment: Have you been successful with this in SwiftUI?

Comment: Sadly not. I went with a more standard (and less pretty) non-grouped list style instead.